# Incredible annoying behavior with GRUNT

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean.io

We're using Mean.io for a project and getting erratic behavior from Grunt.

When we make changes on different files (while Grunt is running, of course), Grunt may detect the changes or not. HTML changes are usually detected by Grunt, but CSS/JS changes not.

And even worst, we often have to reboot (CTRL+C, grunt -f) Grunt to make it displays the project correctly because it prints random errors that actually don't exist. And thus the page is not displayed correctly in the browser.

For instance:

```
/vagrant/vavel/node_modules/dependable/index.js:115
        throw new Error("dependency '" + name + "' was not registered");
          ^
Error: dependency 'access' was not registered
```

Or:

```
/vagrant/vavel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:323
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
        ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

These errors just disappear if we restart Grunt again (using "rs" or CTRL+C + grunt -f).

In fact, sometimes there is not any error displayed in console and the page doesn't show up well.

Are we doing something wrong with ow we are using Grunt?

---

Gruntfile.js

cat Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

var paths = {
  js: ['*.js', 'test/**/*.js', '!test/coverage/**', '!bower_components/**', 'packages/**/*.js', '!packages/**/node_modules/**'],
  html: ['packages/**/public/**/views/**', 'packages/**/server/views/**'],
  css: ['!bower_components/**', 'packages/**/public/**/css/*.css']
};

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  }

  // Project Configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    assets: grunt.file.readJSON('config/assets.json'),
    clean: ['bower_components/build'],
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: paths.js,
        tasks: ['jshint'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      html: {
        files: paths.html,
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          interval: 500
        }
      },
      css: {
        files: paths.css,
        tasks: ['csslint'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      all: {
        src: paths.js,
        options: {
          jshintrc: true
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      core: {
        options: {
          mangle: false
        },
        files: '<%= assets.core.js %>'
      }
    },
    csslint: {
      options: {
        csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
      },
      src: paths.css
    },
    cssmin: {
      core: {
        files: '<%= assets.core.css %>'
      }
    },
    nodemon: {
      dev: {
        script: 'server.js',
        options: {
          args: [],
          ignore: ['node_modules/**'],
          ext: 'js,html',
          nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
          delayTime: 1,
          cwd: __dirname
        }
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
      }
    },
    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        require: [
          'server.js',
          function() {
            require('meanio/lib/util').preload(__dirname + '/packages/**/server', 'model');
          }
        ]
      },
      src: ['packages/**/server/tests/**/*.js']
    },
    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      }
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
      }
    }
  });

  //Load NPM tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  //Default task(s).
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'concurrent']);
  } else {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'jshint', 'csslint', 'concurrent']);
  }

  //Test task.
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);

  // For Heroku users only.
  // Docs: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/wiki/Deploying-on-Heroku
  grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', ['cssmin', 'uglify']);
};
```

Comment: There is no way to help you without knowing what your tasks defined in your grunt file are; what tasks are failing, how you're running grunt, etc.

Comment: We've not touched the Gruntfile.js. It's a default and clean Mean.io installation. On the other hand, there are not failed tasks, at least we can't see any kind of error in console. Sometimes, just some random JavaScript errors like the ones i posted in the main post. Anyway, i'll post my Gruntfile.js.

Comment: This has nothing to do with grunt at all. Removing grunt tag.  This is an issue with how you've set up mean.io.

Comment: These happened a lot on our team too.

Comment: tkone, i sincerely doubt it. I just followed up their instructions and there is not any special setup for the project. We haven't modified any configuration file, at least, not without the main Mean.io tutorial say it.